# Even thought I have set the $PATH variable still command not found

Tags: macos, path

I am using a Mac. The output of echo $PATH gives:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/amazon/bin
```

But when I run

```
chmod +x mwinit
```

It gives me the following error:

```
chmod: mwinit: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing? I have been trying from a long time to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to know where your mwinit file is for this you might want to try to run a `whereis mwinit`.

then you can use the chmod command with the full path to mwinit or
run the following instead :

`chmod +x $(whereis -b mwinit | cut -d' ' -f2)`

then you do `hash -r` to be ready to go !

(hash -r will reload your shell hash-table for the executable w/i your $PATH)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25841976)

Comment: well if a program is not executable a "which prog" won't locate it, while a whereis might, this location information required to fix the problem, other solution doesn't provide a mean to know where the "target" is.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Thanks for extending it, so it provides a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` only gets you to the executable (`chmod` in this case), you still must either be in the directory containing the target (`mwinit` in this case), or you must use the full path. Otherwise `chmod` doesn't know where to find your file.